# Go interface: interface not implemented even though it is

Tags: go, go-interface

Can someone explain to me why this kind of implementation is not allowed in go?
I have a function that takes the interface the function is defined in as an argument. This throws an error.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Anode int

func (a Anode) IsLess(node Anode) bool { return a < node }

type Node interface {
    IsLess(node Node) bool
}

func test(a, b Node) bool {
    return a.IsLess(b)
}
func main() {
    a := Anode(1)
    b := Anode(2)
    fmt.Println(test(a, b))
}
```

Comment: Basically a duplicate. No covariance, interface signature must match literal.

Answer (score 6):

The signatures are not the same. The argument types are different:

```
IsLess(Node) bool  // interface argument type is `Node` 
IsLess(Anode) bool // method argument type is `Anode`
```

To fix this - change your method to use argument type `Node`.
You'll then need a `Value()` method to convert `Anode` into a comparable type (e.g. `int`):

```
func (a Anode) IsLess(node Node) bool { return a.Value() < node.Value() }
func (a Anode) Value() int            { return int(a) }
```

And add this to your interface definition:

```
type Node interface {
    IsLess(node Node) bool
    Value() int // <-- add this
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/TmGcBpUQzGs