# Generics: Implement nested interfaces

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to implement the interface `Interface` using generics. It has one method which accepts another Interface as a parameter:

```golang
type SubInterface interface {
    SendResponse(string)
}

type Interface interface {
    Subscribe(SubInterface)
}
```

I've come up with the following generic version of those interfaces:

```golang
type GenericSubInterface[T any] interface {
    SendResponse(T)
}

type GenericInterface[Res any] interface {
    Subscribe(GenericSubInterface[Res])
}
```

I would expect `GenericInterface[string]` to be assignable to `Interface` but it somehow isn't.

```golang
var a Interface
var b GenericInterface[string]

//  cannot use b (variable of type GenericInterface[string]) as Interface value in assignment: GenericInterface[string] does not implement Interface (wrong type for method Subscribe)
//      have Subscribe(GenericSubInterface[string])
//      want Subscribe(SubInterface)
a = b
```

Creating a generic implementation of `Interface` doesn't work either:

```golang
type GenericImplementation[Res any] struct {
}

func (i *GenericImplementation[Res])Subscribe(ss GenericSubInterface[Res]) {
    var msg Res
    ss.SendResponse(msg)
}
```

```golang
//  cannot use &GenericImplementation[string]{} (value of type *GenericImplementation[string]) as Interface value in variable declaration: *GenericImplementation[string] does not implement Interface (wrong type for method Subscribe)
//      have Subscribe(GenericSubInterface[string])
//      want Subscribe(SubInterface)
var c Interface = &GenericImplementation[string]{}
```

What seems weird to me is that the sub-interfaces are assignable to each other:

```golang
var d SubInterface
var e GenericSubInterface[string]

// works fine
d = e
```

The problem only seems to occur when interfaces are nested somehow. Is there any way around this that I can implement `Interface` using generics for types other than `string`?

[Full playground example](https://go.dev/play/p/hwe2JmQPBAd)

Answer (score 3):

First, read [Go interface: interface not implemented even though it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63586621/go-interface-interface-not-implemented-even-though-it-is). The very first sentence of [@colm.anseo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218512/colm-anseo)'s answer already summarizes the issue:

> The signatures are not the same. The argument types are different

Then read [How to implement generic interfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72034479/how-to-implement-generic-interfaces). Values of type `SubInterface` are assignable to **a particular instantiation** of `GenericSubInterface`, namely `GenericSubInterface[string]`, because the methods end up being identical — `SendResponse(string)`.

`Interface` is not assignable to `GenericInterface[string]` because the methods end up being **not identical**. The error message is as eloquent as it gets:

```
have Subscribe(GenericSubInterface[string])
want Subscribe(SubInterface)
```

You can use the generic version of your interfaces, however the methods must be implemented exactly. So you have to make the function `AcceptInterface` generic too:

```
func AcceptInterface[T any](a GenericInterface[T]) {
}

func main() {
    var b GenericInterface[string]
    AcceptInterface(b)
}
```

Comment: I see, I've misinterpreted this as an issue with generics when actually it isn't. 
If `func AcceptInterface(a Interface)` is not under my control, there's no way to pass it a generic implementation?

Comment: You can pass a generic implementation only if the implementor has the same method signatures *after instantiation*

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to satisfy `Interface` using generics that fits my use case. Any nested interface has to be specified as an additional type parameter. This makes the instantiation a little more verbose but allows for `GenericInterface` and `GenericImplementation` to satisfy `Interface`:

```golang
// Interface

type GenericInterface[Res any, Arg GenericSubInterface[Res]] interface {
    Subscribe(Arg)
}

var a Interface
var b GenericInterface[string, SubInterface]
a = b // works

// Implementation

type GenericImplementation[Res any, Arg GenericSubInterface[Res]] struct {
}

func (i *GenericImplementation[Res, Arg]) Subscribe(ss Arg) {
    var msg Res
    ss.SendResponse(msg)
}

var c Interface = &GenericImplementation[string, SubInterface]{} // works
```

Comment: just don't forget that `GenericInterface[string, SubInterface]` is the *only* instantiation that is assignable to `Interface`